# 'You provided an invalid object' error when subscribing rxjs observable

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

So i'm trying to make some dynamic query calls to my FireStore within an angular app. Using angular/fire 5.1.

Here is the deal:

```
products$: Observable<ProductModel[]>;
name$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
/*..*/
this.products$ = this.name$.pipe(
  switchMap(query =>
    this.db.collection<ProductModel>('products', ref => ref.orderBy('name').startAt(query)).valueChanges()
  )
);
dataService.getDataObservable().subscribe(data => {
  this.name$.next(data);
  }
);
this.products$.subscribe(items => {
  console.log(items);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

this doesn't catch the error. instead i am getting a TypeError in the console:

---

**core.js:12632 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

---

What am i doing wrong there and what is the best practice for dynamic querying. Unfortunately angular/fire package doesn't provide good doc online (at least for free).

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit some Value from Behavior Subject. So you can receive the observable value using pipe operator.

```
this.name$.next('hi');
this.name$.pipe(
  switchMap(query =>{
    return query;
  })
).subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. actually i don't even want to subscribe the BehaviorSubject. I want to subscribe 'products$' and be able to use the data.